# Javascript - Create paragraph from random array of words

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I am trying to take a set of words for example...

```
Apple
Banana
The
Orange
House
Boat
Lake
Car
And
```

I want to be able to output 50 of these words at random to a div using javascript.  Is this possible and if so should I be looking at putting them into an array or something similar?

Comment: Of course this is possible. Start with an array ... and if you have any specific problem, you can come back to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's possible and here is a quick and dirty example of it. (Sorry I've got no more time atm)

```
var words = ['apple', 'beer', 'cake', 'potato', 'orange'],
    div = document.getElementById('foo');

for(i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    div.innerHTML += ' ' + words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
}
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/LavY5/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's possible, using the `Math.random` function to generate the text and `innerHTML` to fill a div.

The array make it easier to get the words.

```
var tokens = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'The' ...];
var text = '';
for (var i=0; i<50; i++) {
    text += tokens[Math.floor(Math.random()*tokens.length)];
}
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = text;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use an array. To get a random word from such an array, use the following:

```
function getRandomWord() {
   var words = ['Apple','Banana','The','Orange','House','Boat','Lake','Car','And'];
   return words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
}
```

Then invoke that function to whatever extent you like.

```
var paragraph = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    paragraph.push(getRandomWord());

$('#my-container').text( paragraph.join(' ') );
```

Comment: Did he say, that he is using jQuery? :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, put all your words in an `Array`. Then apply the [**Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle), to shuffle/randomize your words array. Then, take a `slice` of the array of your specified size, and print those words to the HTML:

```
var words = [ "Apple", "Banana", "The", "Orange", "House", "Boat", "Lake", "Car", "And" ];

function fisherYates (arr) {
  var n = arr.length;
  while (n) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * n--);
    var temp = arr[n];
    arr[n] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
  }
  return arr;
}

fisherYates(words); // shuffle
var randomParagraph = words.slice(0, 5).join(" "); // take 5 random words
document.write(randomParagraph);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R66Rp/)**.
​

Comment: I think this isn't right, the last remaining position is already shuffled, and to exchange it with itself is useless. Take a look on the last table of [section *Modern method* in the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle&oldid=626136517#Modern_method)

Comment: I also think the shuffling is a bit distracting for this case.

Comment: The `n--` I understand, but seems a bit dangerous, I'd give it another line. Howsoever, if you can convince me about the need for F&Y her, I'll vote up ;)

Comment: I see the problem of "randomizing an array" as a different wording for "shuffling an array", for which Fisher-Yates was designed for. Thus, if you have an array of, say, 1000 words, and you want to take N random ones, you have two options: 1) Do N iterations and take a random word each time, and having to worry about the possibility of picking the same word every time; 2) Randomizing/Shuffling the array, and then pick the first N words (this avoids duplication of elements as well).